# How does std::unordered-map.clear() work when keys do not own the underlying memory?

Tags: c++, c++17

I came across a relatively weird segfault when using a std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::string_view> with MSVC 2017, compiling for C++17, with a simple debug build.

The TLDR here is that calling .clear() on my map after the char arrays to which the string views were 'looking at' changed or went out of scope led to a segfault.

After investigating the internals of the unordered map, it seems to me that calling .clear() assumes that one can correctly compute the hash of every key in the map. This I guess is just a way to satisfy the O(container_size) time complexity of clear that the standard states.

Now in the case of my unordered map of string views, I believe the hashing of a string view is based on the hashing of the char array that it looks at, therefore if the char array went out of scope,or was modified in any way, my hashing would be completely off, leading to the segfault.

However, this seems a very odd way to implement the .clear() function of the unordered map container. Why isn't .clear() relying on some sort of internal state to decide where to start erasing from when a call to clear happens? In this way, it wouldn't have to rely on the keys hash being correctly computable when a call to .clear() happens.

Does this imply that one can't safely call .clear() on an unordered_map storing keys that do not own the underlying memory, and whose hashing are based on the underlying memory?

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Thanks!

I would expect the call to .clear() to never lead to UB, no-matter what keys I am using in my map. I would expect the call to .clear() to be completely independent on hashing of the keys themselves.

Comment: I see nothing in [unordered_map::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear) that suggests your expectations.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] supporting your conclusion?

Comment: Irrespective of whether `clear()` should or should not be looking at the unordered map's keys: using `string_view` for a key always end in tears, eventually.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answers! 

Apologies, I am a relative beginner with C++, so my understanding is definitely flawed in many ways! 

This being said, I was looking at the implementation of clear, here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xhash#L1168, 

I belioeve this ends up calling the hashing function here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xhash#L976

However, the answer below seems to make things clear as to why the standard allows this to happen!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard lays down several expectations about [the behavior of keys in any "unordered" container](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/unord.req#5):

> For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the same container, calling `pred(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value. For any key `k` in a container, calling `hash(k)` shall always return the same value.

These are rules that your key objects must abide by. Always: so long as the container exists, these must hold true. And if they don't hold true, you get undefined behavior.

These statements do not provide an exception for `clear` or even the destructor. As such, any implementation is permitted to assume that the container *still works* during any function call, including `clear` or the destructor.

Could one implement the type in a way that `clear` would still work if you broke the rules? Maybe. But they don't have to because your code is the one that's ultimately at fault here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

This definitely explains why this behaviour is possible and I see now that my code was indeed wrong!

As I am a relative beginner with C++, could you please point me towards where the standard versions are defined for each version, so that I can search those myself before asking relatively silly questions here :)?

Thanks!

Comment: @FrostySnowman Check out https://isocpp.org/ , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp & https://eel.is/c++draft/